# Output the values of the variables of django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

hello i have project on django rest framework and angularjs
often need for debugging output some variable of backend, 
Is there simple a way output the values of the variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the ways with which you can easily debug in Django :

- Simple `print` statements while the `django development server` is running. A simple `print` statement will output the variable verbatim on your `terminal`. This is the easiest way to get your problem sorted (well, it's not the ideal way and is only good if you need to debug less often), Sometimes, you would also feel need to `prettify` your console output for which you can always use `Data Pretty Printer` [pprint documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)
- Django also leverages `django-debug-toolbar`. According to me, this will qualify as the ideal way to debug Django applications. Here is the [documentation](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for the same.
- Now, since you have DRF already installed and are already working with it, you must be familiar that `django-rest-framework` `APIView` is the base class for all the `Browsable APIs` on the `DRF Docs` page. You can also visit the API page (URL is configurable) and can simulate API calls from the panel. You can debug through this by returning values that you want to debug as `Response` data for specific API.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use debug tool bar

[django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried visiting your API urls in the browser? DRF provides a [Browseable API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/) so you can see lists and object details in the browser.

Comment: Yes, but how do I output the values variables in the function at the post method